# angularjs expand & collapse issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new in angularjs and currently i'm facing this issue.

**Problem**

when i clicked on any of the node, all the nodes will be expanded or collapsed.
For example : **(Before clicking on the node)**

[image: image1]

**After clicking on the node**

[image]

**Code**

```
 <div class="item">Data Visualization</div>
      <div class= "item">
           <i class="icon ion-arrow-right-b" ng-model="collapsed" ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed"><strong> &nbsp;AGV Mileage Vs Timestamp</strong></i>
           <div ng-show="collapsed">&nbsp;&nbsp; 

              <div id ="agvmileage">
                <div class = "horizon">
                    <canvas width="960" height="120">
                    <script src="/static/js/frontend/cubi-agv.js"></script>
                </div>
              </div>

           </div>
      </div>

      <div class= "item">
           <i class="icon ion-arrow-right-b" ng-model="collapsed" ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed"><strong> &nbsp;Board Temperature Vs Timestamp</strong></i>
           <div ng-show="collapsed">&nbsp;&nbsp; 

              <div id ="agvmileage">
                <div class = "horizon">
                    <canvas width="960" height="120">
                    <script src="/static/js/frontend/cubi-agv.js"></script>
                </div>
              </div>

           </div>
      </div>

      <div class= "item">
           <i class="icon ion-arrow-right-b" ng-model="collapsed" ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed"><strong> &nbsp;Laser Sensor Output Vs Timestamp</strong></i>
           <div ng-show="collapsed">&nbsp;&nbsp; 

              <div id ="agvmileage">
                <div class = "horizon">
                    <canvas width="960" height="120">
                    <script src="/static/js/frontend/cubi-agv.js"></script>
                </div>
              </div>

           </div>
      </div>

      <div class= "item">
           <i class="icon ion-arrow-right-b" ng-model="collapsed" ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed"><strong> &nbsp;Battery Current Vs Timestamp</strong></i>
           <div ng-show="collapsed">&nbsp;&nbsp; 

              <div id ="agvmileage">
                <div class = "horizon">
                    <canvas width="960" height="120">
                    <script src="/static/js/frontend/cubi-agv.js"></script>
                </div>
              </div>

           </div>
      </div>
```

And if possible, how can i declare the "data visualization" as parent node and 
  others as child node then perform expand and collapse.

Please enlighten me on this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Its because you have bound all the `ng-show` directives to the same variable `collapsed`. You need a separate variable so you can collapse/expand independently. You should check out `ng-repeat` as you should probably be iterating over an array of objects to remove all the duplication in your template and at the same time you can bind your `ng-show` to a property of the object within the `ng-repeat`

Comment: noted with thanks =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each item needs to have its own separate `collapsed` state. For example:

**Item 1**

```
<i ng-model="collapsedMileage" ng-click="collapsedMileage = !collapsedMileage">
    <strong>AGV Mileage Vs Timestamp</strong>
</i>
<div ng-show="collapsedMileage">
    <!-- the rest of your template -->
</div>
```

**Item 2**

```
<i ng-model="collapsedLaser" ng-click="collapsedLaser = !collapsedLaser">
    <strong>Laser Sensor Output Vs Timestamp</strong>
</i>
<div ng-show="collapsedLaser ">
    <!-- the rest of your template -->
</div>
```

**Item 3**

```
<i ng-model="collapsedBattery" ng-click="collapsedBattery = !collapsedBattery">
    <strong>Battery Current Vs Timestamp</strong>
</i>
<div ng-show="collapsedBattery">
    <!-- the rest of your template -->
</div>
```

Comment: Great, glad to help!